# How to detect when pytest test case got AssertionError?

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, pytest

I am using pytest to automate project test. I want to take some unique actions like "save_snapshot()" only when a test case fails.

Do we have something like that in pytest?

I have tried to achieve this using the teardown_method() But this method is not getting executed when a test case fails.

- without using fixtures please.

Comment: Try to use pytest plugin api like [pytest_runtest_teardown](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_runtest_teardown) and family.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov can you comment on my idea ? i will be glad for your opinion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for this issue by using python decorator for each test in class:

```
def is_failed_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except AssertionError:
            cls_obj = args[0]
            cur_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
            func_name = func.__name__
            # Save_snapshot().
            raise
    return wrapper

# Tests class
@is_failed_decorator
def test_fail(self):
    assert False
```

worked for me :D